# HibernateTemplate findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam very slow

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am working on a new project on some existing code . It uses [HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.html#findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.Object:A-) to invoke a stored procedure in the database .

When I execute the stored procedure on the database , it executes in 2 or 3 seconds . But I execute it via the HibernateTemplate method , it takes anywhere between 2 to 34 minutes .

When I turn showsql on , I see that there are thousands of select statements being triggered . Any pointers on possible reasons for why this could happen .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by a bad configuration of 2nd level cache and query cache.

Check that expiration time of your query cache is the same as the expiration time for the 2nd level cache - for all entities fetched by your query -. (look into ehcache config file -or any other 2nd level cache provider you are using-)

Comment: Thanks . Where do I set the query cache expiry  times

Comment: If you are using ehcache there is file named ehcache-config.xml (or something like that) with an element for the query cache : <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"... timeToLiveSeconds=xyz ...

Comment: Yes we are using ehcache . But I don't have that set up . Wil give it a shot now .

Comment: I assume once this is set I should use the criteria.setcachesble(true ) or query.setcacheable(true) ?

Comment: You can try this : hibernateTemplate.setCacheQueries(false) to see if it change anything (it will be a good indication that the problem is there.)

Comment: Ok will try that ! Thank you . Also the entity that the result of the store procedure is trying to populate with its results , has lot of child entities at multiple levels . And the mappings are set to lazy=false and fetch =select . Could this be a cause for all those select statements

Comment: I set the setcachequeries(false) and I still see the select statements . I am wondering if it is because of some eager loading

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your code/mapping/db schema

Comment: I can send some configuration to you - is there a way to attach files here

Comment: List<parentEntity> entities = session.createcriteria(ParentEntity.class).list();  triggers thousands of  select statements . When RHS result is copied into LHS . I don't have the freedom to change the hibernate mappings . Is there a way to prevent  this without changing the mapping attributes lazy and fetch